# openssl decoding does not work with echo

Tags: linux, openssl, echo, base64

I encrypted some data:

```
echo -n aaaa | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -K E5E9FA1BA31ECD1AE84F75CAAA474F3A -nosalt -out o
```

This decodes it correctly:

```
base64 o | openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -K E5E9FA1BA31ECD1AE84F75CAAA474F3A -nosalt -base64
```

but this fails:

```
echo -n 0y14OkIoAkNcGyXft6qZ8w== | openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -K E5E9FA1BA31ECD1AE84F75CAAA474F3A -nosalt -base64
bad decrypt
140357156597784:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:518:
```

`base64 o` returns `0y14OkIoAkNcGyXft6qZ8w==`.

Why fails the second method?

Comment: `base64 o` outputs a newline, you're suppressing it in your last command.

Comment: You are right, but why is the newline needed?

Answer (score 1):

`base64` is not so picky about the newline:

```
echo -n 0y14OkIoAkNcGyXft6qZ8w== | base64 -d | openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -K E5E9FA1BA31ECD1AE84F75CAAA474F3A -nosalt
```

My guess is you hit a corner case in `openssl`.